# PRISM + MEF -- Can't get regions to work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, regions, prism-4

a bit new to Prismv4 and MEF.

I went through the QuickStarts and tried to combine two of them together, but I can't seem to get it working.

First, I got a Bootstrapper to load the Shell Window.

```
public sealed class ClientBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

        //Add this assembly to export ModuleTracker (Shell is in this Assembly).
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    }

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

This worked fine. The Shell window was shown and a nice Hello World message appeared. Then I tried to create a Region inside the Shell window so I can load a View into that region. I haven't even gotten this to work to even look at moving it to an outside assembly.

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(HelloWorldModule), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.OnDemand)]
public class HelloWorldModule : IModule
{
    [Import(AllowRecomposition = true)]
    private IRegionViewRegistry regionViewRegistry;

    [ImportingConstructor()]
    public HelloWorldModule(IRegionViewRegistry registry)
    {
        this.regionViewRegistry = registry;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion("PrimaryRegion", typeof(Views.HelloWorldView));
    }
}
```

The HelloWorld view (just a simple UserControl that contains a TextBlock) is not being loaded into the region! I guess I'm a bit lost here on how to load in my regions.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this and it works for me, the Module class as follows:

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(HelloWorldModule))]
public class HelloWorldModule : IModule
{

    [Import]
    private IRegionManager regionManager;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        Uri viewNav = new Uri("HelloWorldView", UriKind.Relative);
        regionManager.RequestNavigate("PrimaryRegion", viewNav);
    }
}
```

The View class as follows:

```
[Export("HelloWorldView")]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public partial class HelloWorldView : UserControl
{
    public HelloWorldView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The xaml in HelloWorldView

```
<UserControl x:Class="HelloWorldModule.HelloWorldView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"  mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You will need

```
protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstapper).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(HelloWorldModule.HelloWorldModule).Assembly));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use the view discovery approach?

Have you tried the following:

```
    [ModuleExport(typeof(HelloWorldModule), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.OnDemand)]
public class HelloWorldModule : IModule
{
    private IRegionManager regionManager;      

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public HelloWorldModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    } 

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("PrimaryRegion", typeof(Views.HelloWorldView));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ConfigureAggregateCatalog` method in your `bootstrapper` needs to add the assembly that your `view` is in. Adding the line below to the end of the method should get you past your current problem.

```
this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Views.HelloWorld).Assembly));
```

This can also be done in `XAML` in a `ModuleCatalog`.

Your `Views.HelloWorld` class will also need an `[Export]` attribute added to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's going wrong based on the information you share.
I would suggest looking at the examples and the reference implementation that comes with PRISM4. I guess the reference implementation and a little debugging should help you in finding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ModuleC : IModule
{
    #region IModule Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the module.
    /// </summary>
    public void Initialize()
    {
        /* We register always-available controls with the Prism Region Manager, and on-demand 
         * controls with the DI container. On-demand controls will be loaded when we invoke
         * IRegionManager.RequestNavigate() to load the controls. */

        // Register task button with Prism Region
        var regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TaskButtonRegion", typeof(ModuleBTaskButton));

        /* View objects have to be registered with Unity using the overload shown below. By
         * default, Unity resolves view objects as type System.Object, which this overload 
         * maps to the correct view type. See "Developer's Guide to Microsoft Prism" (Ver 4), 
         * p. 120. */

        // Register other view objects with DI Container (Unity)
        var container = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnityContainer>();
        container.RegisterType<Object, ModuleBRibbonTab>("ModuleBRibbonTab");
        container.RegisterType<Object, ModuleBNavigator>("ModuleBNavigator");
        container.RegisterType<Object, ModuleBWorkspace>("ModuleBWorkspace");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the "answer" part of this post?

Comment: This question is asking about MEF implementation. Unfortunately, the answer provided here is using Unity.